# In Typescript, it is possible to add properties keys using generics?

Tags: typescript

In typescript, it is possible to add properties keys using generics?

```
function f<T extends string>(k: T) {
  return { [k]: 'test'; };
}

const obj = f('foo');
// some how assert that obj.foo exists
```

I have a function like the one above that takes in a key `k` and add that key to an object dynamically using `{[identifier]: 'value'}`.

---

I'm wondering if its possible to capture a string literal type e.g. `'some-key'`/`T extends string` and use the literal in another type. Something like this:

```
interface F<T extends string> {
  [T]: SomeRandomType;
  otherKey: string;
  anotherKey: number;
}

interface SomeRandomType { /* ... */ }

const f: F<'bar'> = /* ... */;
f.otherKey; // should work
f.anotherKey; // should work
f.bar; // should work
```

Any ideas? Is this not possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep, this is possible using a creative combination of [mapped types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [intersection types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types).

You can model the "arbitrary string literal-keyed property" case using a mapped type.

```
type F<Keys extends string> = {
    [K in Keys] : number;
}

const f : F<'bar'> = null;
f.bar;  // typed as a number
f.wibble;  // type error
```

Note that mapped types have to be `type` declarations, not `interface`s. Don't ask me what the difference is!

Then it's a case of layering the additional properties on top using the intersection type operator `&`. For some reason you have to use `&` for this. You're seemingly not allowed to declare these properties as being part of the same object type.

```
type F<Keys extends string> = {
    [K in Keys] : number;
} & {
    additionalKey1 : object;
    additionalKey2 : string;
}
const f : F<'bar'> = null;
f.bar;  // typed as a number
f.additionalKey1;  // typed as an object
```